# Looking for Free Serial Port library Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, serial-port, windowbuilder

I'm looking for a free Serial Port library that **works** with Eclipse Helios, Windows 7 and WindowBuilder.  Also, the library shall be easy to install and have a full example of usage.  Due to project schedule, I can't afford to spend a lot of time trying to get this environment to cooperate.

I found JCommWin32, but that causes problems with WindowBuilder when an instance of the derived class is invoked (I had no content in the derived class, only overloaded "onRead" which was an empty method).

According to many sources on the Web, Sun dropped serial port support for Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use the Windows native API for Serial Port.

Answer (score 0):

Another popular library is RXTX. It is not perfect, but usable.

PS. WindowBuilder vs. Serial Port Library... Are you mixed UI with serial port handling?

Comment: I need to write a GUI application, running on windows 7, that talks to an embedded system using RS232C interface; not USB.  Does this qualify as "mixing"?

Comment: I meant that UI classes contain code for opening a connection, sending/receiving data, etc. Maybe it worth to hide such business out from WindowBuilder. Regarding to RXTX, we use it in production for about 1 year. I heard it may fail in some non-standard situations, but we use it for simple send/receive operations.